# Change the preview image size image upload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This I borrowed online as I started to learn JS. Tried to modify this to suite to my requirement, So I've got two upload buttons next to each other with preview which works fine. But what I'm trying to achieve is to change the dimensions of the preview image once an image is uploaded. Can some one help pointing out where do I make that change? Thank you.

here goes the code:

**HTML**

```
        <input type="file">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.image.upload.preview.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('input[type="file"]').uploadPreview({
                    callback: function(res){
                        res.after.empty()
                        if (res.img){
                            res.after.append($("<br>"),$('<img>',{"Src":res.img.src, "width": (res.img.width>200)?"200":res.img.width}));
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>

        <input type="file">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.image.upload.preview.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('input[type="file"]').uploadPreview1({
                    callback: function(res1){
                        res1.after.empty()
                        if (res1.img){
                            res1.after.append($("<br>"),$('<img>',{"Src":res1.img.src, "width": (res1.img.width>200)?"100":res1.img.width}));
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
```

**and the JS file**

```
(function() {
  var __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

  (function($) {
    $["fn"]["uploadPreview"] = function(o) {
      o = $["extend"]({
        "types": ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"],
        'callback': function() {}
      }, o);
      this["each"](function() {
        var after, before, wrapper;
        wrapper = $("<span>");
        before = $("<span>");
        after = $("<span>");
        $(this)["wrap"](wrapper);
        $(this)["before"](before);
        $(this)["after"](after);
        return $(this)["on"]("change", function() {
          var obj, reader, _ref;
          obj = [];
          obj["target"] = $(this);
          obj["wrapper"] = wrapper;
          obj["before"] = before;
          obj["after"] = after;
          if (this.files && this.files[0] && (_ref = this.files[0].type, __indexOf.call(o.types, _ref) >= 0)) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              var img;
              img = new Image();
              img.onload = function() {
                return o["callback"](obj);
              };
              img.src = e.target.result;
              return obj["img"] = img;
            };
            return reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
          } else {
            return o["callback"](obj);
          }
        });
      });
      $(this)["trigger"]("change");
      return this;
    };
    return this;
  })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP code here?

Comment: @Jorn oh yea ma bad! was working inside a PHP file and mistakenly mentioned as PHP. Corrected as JS!